# The times they are a-changin'

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rhyme, poetry, movies

> Nude, tall and blue,
> Yellow's new love,
> Owl too, though late,
> Under the hood,
> Symmetry in motion, outlawed, good.

This is my first [yadu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yadu_(poetry)), enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The movie is

> Watchmen

> The times they are a-changin'

> The title song

> Nude, tall and blue,

> Dr Manhattan fits this description

> Yellow's new love,

> Both Silk Spectres dress in yellow, and both have love interests that change (or are revealed to have changed in a flashback) in the movie.

> Owl too, though late

> Both Nite Owls have an owl aesthetic. Daniel Dreiberg as Nite Owls is romantically involved with the later of the two Silk Spectres, but arrives too late to stop Ozymandias. (In the comics only Hollis Mason as Nite Owl is late, in the sense that he is dead. He does not appear in the film)

> Under the hood

> Rorschach has a hood, or mask that fits this description. Also, this sort of alludes to Ozymandias keeping his plans under the hood

> Symmetry in motion, outlawed, good.

> The events of the Watchmen mirror the events of the Minutemen who predate them who are outlawed initially. Eventually as a result of Ozymandias's actions they are outlawed again but this time they seem to achieve world peace.